# CodeName One error: cannot find symbol

Tags: codenameone

I have created a simple sample Application with CodeNameOne without any changes.
Certificate and Provisioning file is available and configured as project properties.

IDE: Eclipse
Desktop OS: Windows

> Executing 'Send IOS Debug Build' starts the server build and shows the
>   following error:
>   /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build5327647990993852705xxx/stub/TestBuildDeployStub.java
>   /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build5327647990993852705xxx/stub/TestBuildDeployStub.java:14:
>   error: cannot find symbol private TestBuildDeploy i;
>           ^ symbol:   class TestBuildDeploy location: class TestBuildDeployStub
>   /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build5327647990993852705xxx/stub/TestBuildDeployStub.java:23:
>   error: cannot find symbol i = new TestBuildDeploy();
>           ^ symbol:   class TestBuildDeploy location: class TestBuildDeployStub Note:
>   /var/folders/p7/d3z112yd0156kxkm2p21p8ym0000gn/T/build5327647990993852705xxx/stub/TestBuildDeployStub.java
>   uses or overrides a deprecated API. Note: Recompile with
>   -Xlint:deprecation for details. 2 errors

This is the java class:

```
package com.canda.mario.myapp;


import com.codename1.ui.Display;
import com.codename1.ui.Form;
import com.codename1.ui.Dialog;
import com.codename1.ui.Label;
import com.codename1.ui.plaf.UIManager;
import com.codename1.ui.util.Resources;
import com.codename1.io.Log;
import com.codename1.ui.Toolbar;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * This file was generated by <a href="https://www.codenameone.com/">Codename One</a> for the purpose
 * of building native mobile applications using Java.
 */
public class TestBuildDeploy {

    private Form current;
    private Resources theme;

    public void init(Object context) {
        theme = UIManager.initFirstTheme("/theme");

        // Enable Toolbar on all Forms by default
        Toolbar.setGlobalToolbar(true);

        // Pro only feature, uncomment if you have a pro subscription
        // Log.bindCrashProtection(true);
    }

    public void start() {
        if(current != null){
            current.show();
            return;
        }
        Form hi = new Form("Hi World");
        hi.addComponent(new Label("Hi World"));
        hi.show();
    }

    public void stop() {
        current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
        if(current instanceof Dialog) {
            ((Dialog)current).dispose();
            current = Display.getInstance().getCurrent();
        }
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }

}
```

Comment: If I use the demo app DrSbaitso and rename the package from com.codename1.demos.sbaitso to com.canda.mario.myapp I am getting the same error for the DrSbaitso.class? Any ideas

Answer (score 4):

If you change the package/class of a Codename One application after it's created you need to change it everywhere both in the project and in the `codenameone_settings.properties` that is why we recommend never changing it.

We don't make this process easy since you are married to life when creating a package name. This is used to uniquely identify you in the stores and can't be changed ever once an app is submitted so you need to understand that this isn't something you should do... Give package name deep consideration before creating the app!

Comment: If you need to change the package name, aside from the `codenameone_settings.properties` file and the java packages (for example `com.myapp.example`, is there anywhere else to change the package name?

Comment: That depends on your IDE but it should generally be it see https://www.codenameone.com/blog/deploy-same-mobile-app-template-multiple-times.html