# Parse4cn1 iOS error

Tags: parse4cn1

I'm getting an error while trying to build the Test App for the parse4cn1 library, I took the code that was on github and only modified the package name since it didn't allow me to generate the push certificates with the one it originally had, and changed the credentials corresponding to the parse url and appid.

The error log generated by the build server can be seen on [this link](https://groups.google.com/group/codenameone-discussions/attach/6493bc1e7571b/parse4cn1%20ios%20build%20error.txt?part=0.1&authuser=0&view=1) for more detail.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting probably has to do with the fact that you changed the package name but missed one or more files. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37605899/1291040):

> If you change the package/class of a Codename One application after it's created you need to change it everywhere both in the project and in the `codenameone_settings.properties`

I hope this helps